# Prevent IE from viewing my website?

Tags: internet-explorer, cakephp

I'd like to take elitism to the n-th degree by not allowing Internet Explorer to browse my website.

Is there a way to do such a thing? My website is built upon the CakePHP framework, if that helps.

Comment: "I write software for me, damnit, not the users."

Comment: It's visitors you create your website for. So why do you want to let them go away?

Comment: Consider testing for crappy browsers instead of IE in general. `window.XMLHttpRequest === undefined` will match for old IEs and other ancient browsers for example.

Comment: As much as i hate IE6, @duri is right, as long as you have the latest version of IE, it's fine.

Comment: @JohnFx: I understand the problem with the idea of blocking IE, but the question as it is, is straightforward and almost alright for me. No need for downvotes.

Comment: lol you should redirect them to a page that says something like "IE is an insecure browser and not allowed on this site." Just say something that deters people from using it.

Comment: Thank you, Jason, for understanding. Privacy and Security is of the utmost importance for this application, and that is exactly what I wanted to do. I want to have it take them to a page which will ask them to download Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: @JohnFx notice this article? http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2012/06/kogan-imposing-tax-on-shoppers-who-use-ie7/ :)

Comment: @tigertrussell Ugh. When we make our users work for the computer instead of the other way around we give ourselves a bad name.

Comment: @JohnFx WE didn't do that, MS did. Why is not allowing specific kinds of web browsers so different than having specific clothing or shoes requirements in a brick-and-mortar store?

Comment: It is more like requiring a certain make of car at a drive through window. It's obnoxious.

Comment: requiring a car* and not allowing bikes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it in PHP, you can use the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` variable to read in the user agent and then look to see if it's using IE, and stop loading if so. You'd want to use a regex on the string, with a simple example being:

```
if (preg_match("Internet Explorer", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) == 0) {
    // print message or whatever and abort
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure all IE versions support the following - does require JavaScript though.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://www.google.co.uk/chrome"
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Support for conditional comments will be removed in IE10 (though I don't think anybody will have to use them anymore).

Answer (score 1):

Are you using jQuery in your website?

If so, you could utilize **browser-validator-js** (https://github.com/bml3i/browser-validator-js) to show friendly messages to user if they are using any version of IE. Just include the browser-validator-js and jQuery to the HTML HEAD, and add the below codes to the HTML BODY.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        BrowserValidator.init({
            msie: {
                majorVersionMax: 0,
                prompt: "Unfortunately, this site does not support IE. "
            }
        }).validateBrowser();
    }); 
</script>
```

This is an example: http://blog.bigcay.com/demo/browser_validator_demo.html